/boot/initramfs-linux.img not found Triple Boot: Windows, Debian, Arch
I installed arch for about the third time today, but on my working laptop, with the idea of using arch for work as well. I think I messed up the install, because my current bootloaders live on a 212 MB partition. I made a new 512 one and mounted it there, because it said that my current boot loader was too small. I was hoping that this would override my current one and I could delete it after install... In retrospect I probably should have cleared my current one and made that new one, and do an update-grub once in. I am being a little timid though as this is my work computer. Any ideas as to how I could use one bootloader but not the other. I am getting a little out of element and would be guessing if I tried anything.
I think I’m getting closer to the problem, but I do not know. So far I have

made my good boot partition larger
Deleted the old boot partition
Reinstalled arch Linux using the arch install utility
I manual did my partition with one for root, home, and boot.
I mounted my boot under /boot, but I wonder if it needs to be under /boot/efi. I’ll have to re read about MBR. It gave the same issue again. That the initramfs file can’t be found.
I chrooted into it from the iso ran a command I can’t remember to supposedly remedy the images and tried to boot again, and it didn’t work.
Did a genfstab to see if a new fstab was the problem from my chroot and it gave the same issue.

I’m now stuck. I think that my fstab file is wrong or in general the mount process is incorrect.
EDIT: TO fix the problem, I chrooted into my arch installation from my debian, and ran the grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=arch_grub --recheck I tried previously with the command being under /boot/efi, but after when I updated, I was unable to boot due to the kernel being booted, and the one loaded being different.
I believe I tried to run the same command under my debian installation, thinking that would work, but it didn't. I do not know why it didn't work.

That small partition is the ESP (EFI System Partition) where ALL your bootloaders are installed. If you remove it you won't be able to boot anything previously installed. If this is your work's assigned computer then you shouldn't be installing OSes no matter what, end of story. If it's your own computer you use for work then you can do whatever you want (and face the consequences). You should learn the basics before attempting any dual- or multi-boot setup, not come here after the fact.

I'd like to think that I do know the basics. In retrospect I made some bad decisions. I have started to move everything over and see if I can make it bigger. It is my own computer. I'm in my debian install now and I will remake everything. If you think you know the best approach to this I am curious to hear it. I have a backup computer and backed up everything prior to changing anything so if I brick the computer its not a big deal just more work for me.

I have read the install guide a couple times. I have been using linux for a couple years and I have my Linux+ I don't think that I am a beginner and have no clue what I am doing. I made some poor decisions though, and people here generally have some good ideas.

Some distros like to install additional stuff in the ESP so they complain when the installer finds out a smaller albeit typical ESP created by Windows or Debian (Ubuntu currently creates a 512MB one). Knowing this either you create a bigger one in another driveand point the installer to that one (manual partitioning) or you use tools to manage partitions and make the original one bigger (a very risky move, BTW).


I don't think that I am a beginner* Well, "beginner" is exactly what transpired from the way you wrote this question. You never mentioned EFI or ESP so we must assume this concept was somehow alien at the time of posting. Hopefully not now after being explained to you.


Furthermore, Arch Linux is a very advanced distro and NOT beginner friendly as Debian. That you were able to follow a wizard provided by the Debian installer and end up with a functional dual-boot Debian(Windows does NOT mean you can do the same as easily with Arch, let alone a triple boot.

I have been downloading distros left and right for the two years. Downloading arch three times. I have arch on my personal computer and have a pretty nice set up on it, and I am tired of not being able to use the AUR on my work computer. How outdated all of debians packages are have been bothering me. I dont really care if I break this computer, I will just reinstall stuff. I have gone for the very risk move. It was a pretty awful idea that I had to make two on the same drive. I will delete the one that I made in arch and it makes sense that you should not have two on the same drive

I made the partition larger and it still cannot find the image. I will do a cp - r from where I created the rogue bootloader to my good one and see if that will do the trick. Is there a better way to do this?

I cannot seem to mount it. Is there a way that I can install that image into the current bootloader that I have? I may just redo the install but correctly if I cannot figure it out. But  I feel like there is a way to remedy the one that I have without having to undo work of earlier today.

Changan could you not leave the question downvoted so I could see what other people think? I don’t why you would downvote this as it seems to be a relevant problem on the right forum.

(This answer is written with the assumption that one same dedicated partition/filesystem is shared by both Linux installations for /boot.)
Note that grub does not leverage fstab to locate the filesystem in which the kernel and initramfs images reside. Instead some identifier (UUID or so, I never really know for sure) of the filesystem is embedded in the EFI executable generated when grub-install is performed. Therefore, you'll need to reinstall grub (bootloader-wise, not system package-wise) if you are replacing the filesystem that is used for /boot (especially if the new filesystem is placed on a partition that has a different number and that partition isn't going to be the ESP; because that means grub won't be looking in the right one even if it relies on the partition number relatively, like "partition #N of the disk that this EFI executable is on", to locate the files). Also make sure that the correct filesystem is mounted on /boot before you perform the reinstallation. (That's assuming you don't need to chroot; if e.g. you'll re-install grub after chroot /mnt, then it should be mounted on /mnt/boot.)
For the record, a significant part of grub, e.g. its modules, is installed to the current /boot (as in, what is mounted there or what contains it upon grub installation) as well unless specified otherwise. More precisely grub uses the way mentioned above to store / locate where that part is, and because it is by default installed to where the kernel and initramfs images are, it will hence be able to locate those "out-of-the-box" as well.)
But certainly you should update the fstab of both installations accordingly, so that when there is kernel update and/or initramfs regeneration, the new images will not go to the old filesystem/partition.
(Btw, to state the obvious, if there is a dedicated/separate filesystem mounted on /boot/efi, make sure that you unmount it first before you unmount the old /boot, and mount it back after you have mounted the new /boot. It is also crucial that you have it mounted before you reinstall grub.)
P.S. I don't know for sure if under any circumstances the UEFI boot entry pointing to the EFI executable on the old /boot (assuming the partition used for /boot is also the ESP) will be not replaced but instead a new entry is registered to the UEFI. When that happens to be the case, you will need to make sure you boot the correct entry to see expected outcomes (at least when the old partition has not been wiped yet -- albeit certain UEFI firmware may not know to ignore/skip entries that are no longer "valid").

Some more information: /boot/efi is the usual (like "near-de facto standard", I would say) directory where (the filesystem on) the EFI system partition (ESP) would be mounted on, if a dedicated partition is used as the ESP (i.e., it is not used for /boot). If you do not mind FAT32 being the filesystem used for /boot, you can also use the /boot partition as the ESP, in which case /boot/efi will not be a mountpoint, but instead there will be a /boot/EFI (instead of /boot/efi/EFI) that contains directories (named e.g. debian / grub) that in turn contain EFI executables. With that said, if you start from a distro installer that has the "default policy/plan" of having a dedicated ESP, then you may want to keep the installation that way. (It's not exactly crucial to have that mounted / added to the fstab of Arch if you started with Debian and has no intention to re-install grub after you have booted Arch.)

Ok I will reinstall grub when I chroot into arch sometime later today. I will let you know what the outcome is. One thing I don't understand is " if you are replacing the filesystem that is used for /boot". I dont think that I am replacing the filesystem used for /boot, just trying to add a a grub entry for arch. Other than that, great explanation of how grub works to start in OS.

@Bill For the record replacing the filesystem that is used for /boot means like re-formatting (i.e. mkfs) the same partition used for /boot or "switching" /boot to (the filesystem on) some other partition (like if you for reasons decided to keep the old one untouched).

I did a grub install from my debian partition and a grubmkconfig. Neither of them worked. I think that I told arch, that the boot loader is under /boot not /boot/efi. I am going to do ANOTHER reinstall of arch to see if I can get this thing working. This time I will mount boot under /boot/mnt when going through the arch install menu.

When I do an update-grub and a grubmkconfig, it seems to run an OS prober. That should be what is inteded by doing a grub-install correct? I do not think that I need to fully reinstall grub for it to be able to boot in, as I am getting the same issue after running that command(I made sure that I was mounted into my arch when I did).

Aww, I now see that there is no grub file in my /boot dir in arch. I will do what I can when chrooted in
